# jsPDF HTML to PDF cut the html between pages

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I have used jsPDF `^2.5.1` to generate PDF from dynamic data. The issue is when PDF create with one or more pages and sometimes the text is cut(half one page and half the second page).

Please check this [link](https://i.imgur.com/GeF4XMK.png)  to check excect issue

```js
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [1665, 1000]);
doc.addFileToVFS("Nunito.ttf", font);
doc.addFont("Nunito.ttf", "Nunito", "normal");
doc.setFont("Nunito-ExtraBold", "bold");

let x = '<style>@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap");</style><html><body><div id="pdfmain" style="width:100vw; page-break-after: always;"><div style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px; background: #f5f5f5;" class="el-col-xl-12 is-guttered"><span style="font-size: 12px; float: right;">07/06/2023</span><div style="justify-content: center; display: grid; width: 100%;"><img src="http://192.168.101.111:3000/logo.png" alt="logo"></div> <div style="text-align: center;"> <span style="color: #21344f; font-size: 21px; font-weight: 800;">Clients Details - Mr Infinity Client</span></div><div class="card-title"> Personal Details </div> <div class="el-divider el-divider--horizontal" style="border-top: 1px #21344F dashed !important; display: block; height: 1px; width: 100%; margin: 10px 10px 15px 2px"></div><table class="pdf-table" style="width: 100%"> <tbody> <tr> <td width="112px"><b style="font-weight: 700;">Full Name</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Mr Infinity Client</td> <td><b>Email</b></td> <td width="10px">:</td> <td>user@gmail.com</td> </tr> <tr> <td width="112px"><b>Phone</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>+61 445 651 321</td> <td width="112px"><b>Gender</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Male</td> </tr> <tr> <td width="112px"><b>Birth Date</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>1995-06-15</td> <td width="112px"><b>Citizenship</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Permanent Resident / NZ Citizen</td> </tr> <tr><td width="112px"><b>Household Dependants</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>3</td> <td width="112px"><b>Marital Status</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Married</td></tr></tr><td width="112px"><b>Spouse Name</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Maya Sowden</td> <td width="112px"><b>Spouse Gender</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Female</td><tr> <td width="112px"><b>Spouse Citizenshp</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Australian Citizen</td><tr/></tbody></table><div class="card-title"> Address </div> <div class="el-divider el-divider--horizontal" style="border-top: 1px #21344F dashed !important; display: block; height: 1px; width: 100%; margin: 10px 10px 15px 2px"></div><h4 style="color: #21344f; margin: 0px 0px 6px 10px; font-weight: 600;">Address 1</h4><table class="pdf-table" style="width: 100%"> <tbody><tr> <td width="112px"><b>Full Address</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td colspan="4">2 Spencer Street GHEERULLA QLD 4574</td> </tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>Unit / Street</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>2 Spencer</td><td width="112px"><b>Suburb</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>QLD</td></tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>State</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>Western Australia</td><td width="112px"><b>Country</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>Australia</td></tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>Postcode</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>4574</td><td width="112px"><b>Unit Number</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>44562112</td></tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>Street Number</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>2</td><td width="112px"><b>Street Name</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>Spencer Street</td></tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>Time at Address (Years)</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>2</td><td width="112px"><b>Time at Address (Months)</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table><div class="el-divider el-divider--horizontal border-light" style="display: block; height: 1px; width: 100%; margin: 10px 10px 15px 2px !important;"></div><h4 style="color: #21344f; margin: 0px 0px 6px 10px; font-weight: 600;">Address 2</h4><table class="pdf-table" style="width: 100%"> <tbody><tr> <td width="112px"><b>Full Address</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td colspan="4">53 Savages Road SUNNYBANK QLD 4109</td> </tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>Unit / Street</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>Savages</td><td width="112px"><b>Suburb</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>QLD</td></tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>State</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>Victoria</td><td width="112px"><b>Country</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>Australia</td></tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>Postcode</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>4109</td><td width="112px"><b>Unit Number</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>547899</td></tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>Street Number</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>53</td><td width="112px"><b>Street Name</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>Savages</td></tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>Time at Address (Years)</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>3</td><td width="112px"><b>Time at Address (Months)</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>6</td></tr></tbody></table><div class="card-title"> Current Employment Details </div> <div class="el-divider el-divider--horizontal" style="border-top: 1px #21344F dashed !important; display: block; height: 1px; width: 100%; margin: 10px 10px 15px 2px"></div><table class="pdf-table" style="width: 100%"> <tbody> <tr> <td width="112px"><b>Employment Type</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Full Time</td> <td><b>Employment Status</b></td> <td width="10px">:</td> <td>Primary Employment</td> </tr> <tr> <td width="112px"><b>Occupation</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Lorem ipsum</td> <td width="112px"><b>Industry</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Lorem ipsum</td> </tr> <tr> <td width="112px"><b>Time at employer (Years) </b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>2</td> <td width="112px"><b>Time at employer (Months)</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>0</td> </tr> <tr> <td width="112px"><b>Employer Business Name</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsum</td> <td width="112px"><b>Employer Contact Person</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsum</td> </tr> <tr> <td width="112px"><b>Employer Contact Number</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>+61 856 254 478</td> </tr> </tbody> </table><div class="card-title"> Employer Address </div> <div class="el-divider el-divider--horizontal" style="border-top: 1px #21344F dashed !important; display: block; height: 1px; width: 100%; margin: 10px 10px 15px 2px"></div><table class="pdf-table" style="width: 100%"> <tbody><tr> <td width="112px"><b>Full Address</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td colspan="4">10 Redesdale Rd STRATHFIELDSAYE VIC 3551</td> </tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>Unit / Street</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>Redesdale</td><td width="112px"><b>Suburb</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>STRATHFIELDSAYE</td></tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>State</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>New South Wales</td><td width="112px"><b>Country</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>Australia</td></tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>Postcode</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>3551</td><td width="112px"><b>Unit Number</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>8546662</td></tr><tr><td width="112px"><b>Street Number</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>10</td><td width="112px"><b>Street Name</b></td><td width="10px"><b>:</b></td><td>Redesdale Rd</td></tr></tbody></table><div class="card-title"> Previous Employment Details </div> <div class="el-divider el-divider--horizontal" style="border-top: 1px #21344F dashed !important; display: block; height: 1px; width: 100%; margin: 10px 10px 15px 2px"></div><h4 style="color: #21344f; margin: 0px 0px 6px 10px; font-weight: 600;">Previous Employment 1</h4><table class="pdf-table" style="width: 100%"> <tbody> <tr> <td width="112px"><b>Occupation</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Lorem ipsum </td> <td width="112px"><b>Employment Basis</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </td> </tr> <tr> <td width="112px"><b>Income</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>$180,000</td> <td width="112px"><b>Employer Business Name</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Lorem ipsum </td> </tr> <tr> <td width="112px"><b>Time at employer (Years ) </b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>4</td> <td width="112px"><b>Time at employer (Months)</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>0</td> </tr> </tbody> </table><div class="el-divider el-divider--horizontal border-light" style="display: block; height: 1px; width: 100%; margin: 10px 10px 15px 2px !important;"></div><h4 style="color: #21344f; margin: 0px 0px 6px 10px; font-weight: 600;">Previous Employment 2</h4><table class="pdf-table" style="width: 100%"> <tbody> <tr> <td width="112px"><b>Occupation</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </td> <td width="112px"><b>Employment Basis</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Lorem ipsum Lorem</td> </tr> <tr> <td width="112px"><b>Income</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>$190,000</td> <td width="112px"><b>Employer Business Name</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>Lorem ipsum </td> </tr> <tr> <td width="112px"><b>Time at employer (Years ) </b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>5</td> <td width="112px"><b>Time at employer (Months)</b></td> <td width="10px"><b>:</b></td> <td>0</td> </tr> </tbody> </table><div class="card-title"> Income Details </div> <div class="el-divider el-divider--horizontal" style="border-top: 1px #21344F dashed !important; display: block; height: 1px; width: 100%; margin: 10px 10px 15px 2px"></div><table class="pdf-table" style="width: 100%"><thead><tr><th>Income Type</th><th>Income Amount</th><th>Frequency</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Commission</td><td>$1,000</td><td>Monthly</td> </tr><tr><td>Commission</td><td>$20,000</td><td>Monthly</td> </tr><tr><td>Overtime</td><td>$15,000</td><td>Fortnightly</td> </tr><tr><td>Commission</td><td>$18,000</td><td>Monthly</td> </tr></tbody> </table><div class="card-title"> Assets ($406,367) </div> <div class="el-divider el-divider--horizontal" style="border-top: 1px #21344F dashed !important; display: block; height: 1px; width: 100%; margin: 10px 10px 15px 2px"></div><table class="pdf-table" style="width: 100%"> <thead> <tr> <th>Type</th> <th>Owner</th> <th>Asset Value</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody><tr> <td>Investment Property</td> <td>Primary Applicant</td> <td>$150,000</td> </tr><tr> <td>Vehicle</td> <td>Joint(with spouse)</td> <td>$95,000</td> </tr><tr> <td>Vehicle</td> <td>Primary Applicant</td> <td>$16,000</td> </tr><tr> <td>Shares</td> <td>Joint(with Other)</td> <td>$85,000</td> </tr><tr> <td>Term deposit</td> <td>Joint(with spouse)</td> <td>$60,000</td> </tr><tr> <td>Vehicle</td> <td>Primary Applicant</td> <td>$367</td> </tr></tbody> </table></tbody> </table><div class="card-title"> Liabilities </div> <div class="el-divider el-divider--horizontal" style="border-top: 1px #21344F dashed !important; display: block; height: 1px; width: 100%; margin: 10px 10px 15px 2px"></div><table class="pdf-table" style="width: 100%"><thead><tr><th>Type</th> <th>Lender</th> <th>Balance</th><th>Payment</th><th>Frequency</th> <th>Payout</th></tr></thead> <tbody><tr><td>Personal Loan</td> <td>AFG Home Loans - Link</td> <td>$150,000</td><td>$1,000</td> <td>Fortnightly</td> <td>Yes</td></tr><tr><td>Home Loan</td> <td>AFG Home Loans - Align</td> <td>$20,000</td><td>$2,500</td> <td>Weekly</td> <td>No</td></tr><tr><td>Vehicle Loan</td> <td>AMP Bank</td> <td>$1,800</td><td>$6,000</td> <td>Fortnightly</td> <td>No</td></tr><tr><td>Short Term Finance</td> <td>Bank of QLD</td> <td>$170,000</td><td>$5,000</td> <td>Yearly</td> <td>No</td></tr></tbody> </table></tbody> </table><div class="card-title"> Bank Accounts </div> <div class="el-divider el-divider--horizontal" style="border-top: 1px #21344F dashed !important; display: block; height: 1px; width: 100%; margin: 10px 10px 15px 2px"></div><table class="pdf-table" style="width: 100%"><thead><tr><th>Account Type</th> <th>Bank Account Number</th> <th>Account Balance</th> <th>Ownership</th></tr></thead> <tbody><tr><td>Saving Account</td> <td>0000123456</td> <td>$1,800,000</td> <td>Primary Applicant</td></tr></tbody> </table></tbody> </table></div></div></body><html>';

doc.html(x, {
  callback: function (doc) {   
    doc.save("users.pdf");
  },
});
```

I have just added my full HTML code.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to use `autoPaging` like `doc.html(x, { autoPaging: true, callback:...`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Thanks for your answer. I have just tried the same but still have the same issue. Just for your reference I have used table format on my HTML

Comment: Can you post full example html + js?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I have just edited the question and added the full HTML. Please check now

Comment: I need the Data too, because without i can't see result.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Please see the question again. I have edited with same HTML static now

Comment: Seems like pretty hard to avoid that bug have you try https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable ?

Comment: ReferenceError: font is not defined

Comment: @JoelPeltonen Thanks for the answer! You can ignore the font. just removed that line

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Not used because I have mixed Html content like div, table, and all things.

Comment: I managed to reproduce the problem and looking at it and how jspdf works... I don't think this will be an easy thing to change :) I would search for alternative PDF generation methods - for generating this kind of stuff that looks like it could work with a very stable structure / templates, I would actually look at PDFKit;  https://pdfkit.org/

Comment: @JoelPeltonen PDFKit will receive this issue instead of jsPDF?

Comment: @KishanBhensadadiya the way PDFKit works is completely different, it's not a HTML to PDF renderer/converter... so there would be new, possibly more interesting and easier to fix issues :) 

Ultimately it comes down to formatting requirements.

Comment: @JoelPeltonen Thank you very much for this research and help. I'll definietly try your approach